# Accessing Newest Mendel 5.0 from Serial Console

Tags: ssh, serial-port, google-coral, mdt

After following the Google Devboard Getting started guide, I finally flashed the devboard with the latest enterprise-eagle-20200724205123 Mendel 5.0 OS. However, when accessing it from the console, I get this:

```
Cannot open access to console, the root account is locked.
See sulogin(8) man page for more details.
```

`mdt devices` does not recognize the board too.
Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error likely means that your file system partition or mounted devices don't match what's in **/etc/fstab** on the device. This could happen for example if you had an SD card auto-mounted in /etc/fstab without the `nofail` param and tried to boot without that card. This would result in the error you're seeing. If that is the case then try inserting an SD card and see if you can login. I belive that the partition table on the Eagle release and the previous release are different, so there might also be a scenario where you updated to Eagle without doing a complete re-install might also cause this error. In that case, I'd try a complete re-install.